# Xamarin.GooglePlayservices.Basement is not compatible with netstandard2.0

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i am having a problem with nuget packages compatibility, originally i just wanted to use firebase.storage in my project but getting this error, any help is greatly appreciated.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1202  Package Xamarin.Firebase.Storage 60.1142.1 is not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Package Xamarin.Firebase.Storage 60.1142.1 supports: monoandroid80 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.0)

Comment: The error is telling that you can not add the package to your NetStd project, it will only work on a `Xamarin.Android`-based one.

Comment: Ty Sushi, and a solution would be ?

Comment: It depends upon what you are trying to achieve, what platforms you are targeting, are you using Xamarin.Forms or the native Android UI, etc...

Comment: Im using xamarin forms in visual studio trying to create an android app for my class project.

Comment: You can start with reading up on Xamarin.Forms dependency service so you can call platform native features from Forms (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction)